# Cannot convert value of type and Argument labels... overloads

Tags: swift

I tried copying a ressource file into my swift coding and I get these errors. 
xCode, Swift: Cannot convert value of type 'NSError?' to expected argument type 'String?' 
and
 Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:, error:)' do not match any available overloads

here is my code

```
public class SKTAudio {
    public var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    public var soundEffectPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    public class func sharedInstance() -> SKTAudio {
        return SKTAudioInstance
    }

    public func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        if (url == nil) {
            print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }

        var error: NSError? = nil
        backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: error)`Cannot convert value of type 'NSError?' to expected argument type 'String?'`
        if let player = backgroundMusicPlayer {
            player.numberOfLoops = -1
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } else {
            print("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
        }
    }

    public func pauseBackgroundMusic() {
        if let player = backgroundMusicPlayer {
            if player.playing {
                player.pause()
            }
        }
    }

    public func resumeBackgroundMusic() {
        if let player = backgroundMusicPlayer {
            if !player.playing {
                player.play()
            }
        }
    }

    public func playSoundEffect(filename: String) {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        if (url == nil) {
            print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }

        var error: NSError? = nil
        soundEffectPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)`Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:, error:)' do not match any available overloads`
        if let player = soundEffectPlayer {
            player.numberOfLoops = 0
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } else {
            print("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
        }
    }
}

private let SKTAudioInstance = SKTAudio()
```

Here's what Im trying to do:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/100496/video-tutorial-how-to-make-a-game-like-flappy-bird-in-swift-part-1-scene-size-and-aspect-ratios

Comment: Swift 2.0 changed the way error handling is done, the method no longer takes a final argument of type `NSError`, you now must use some form of `throw` to handle errors. See the Swift 2.x documentation. From the docs the definition is now: `init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL) throws`.

Comment: It's Xcode. Not xcode, xCode or XCode ;)

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code and found error in the line

```
backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: error)
```

Here you are passing an error instance as an argument whereas the function is expecting a String.

To fix the issue you can pass a String that represnts a file format. For example: `AVFileTypeMPEG4`, `AVFileTypeAppleM4V`, `AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat` etc

```
 backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEG4)
```

Comment: hey, im sorry but I dont get what you mean with the examples. Do you think youd be able to tell me exactly what to do? Sorry Im really new to this and Id really appreciate it

Comment: @Anupam I think you need to address `throws` error handling.